# How to fix issue of family policy requirements with google play

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I tried to publish my app on google play but google play rejected my app due to family policy requirements
First I checked all the content and functionality of my app making sure that It doesn't have any problem with family policy requirements

I also checked the app and remove webengage sdk from it but cannot change AD_ID on app content because the app on production has the sdk
we checked this many times and tries to publish our app

During review, we found that your app is not compliant with the Families Policy Requirements. Specifically, we have determined that your app does not meet the eligibility requirements for the Families Program. Apps in the program must:
Be designed for children or everyone (including children and older audiences).
Include both app and ad content that are relevant and appropriate for children.
Be rated ESRB Everyone or Everyone 10+, or equivalent.
Only use Families Self-Certified Ads SDK Program.

I tried many times to publish it but each time was rejected even after I removed the SDK